# No module named 'PyPDF2._codecs', even after already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf, anaconda3

I have installed `PyPDF2==2.3.0`, but I still get the error below when I `import PyPDF2`.

The error message is:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2._codecs'

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE. This question reflects a bug in PyPDF2 v2.3.0, fixed in 2.3.1. See https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/releases/tag/2.3.1. PLEASE REOPEN

Comment: Follow-up https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418814/request-to-reopen-question

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to provide a [mre]? In specific, a traceback would be needed to clarify whether this is due to an internal problem of the library or an external problem of the code/environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was only present in the PyPI distribution of PyPDF2==2.3.0 for a couple of hours. It was fixed with [release 2.3.1](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/releases/tag/2.3.1). See [#1011](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/1011) for more details

I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2. I'm sorry I caused some headaches.

You can update PyPDF2 via:

```
pip install PyPDF2 --upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED!
I faced the same problem. I installed used pip3, pip everything. But successfully running after installing from below command:

```
pipenv install PyPDF2
```